# Flutter Reset state of AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, download, android-alertdialog, progress

I have read posts on how to refresh the state in an alertDialog. Using a StateBuilder. I am not sure though why this does not work. THis is how the code looks like.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    double _progressValue;
    downloadGoogleDriveFile(_files[index].name, _files[index].googleDriveId, _files[index].size,
      (double progress) {
        setState(() {
          _progressValue = progress;
          print('set state progress value='+_progressValue.toString());
        });
      },
      () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });

    print('progress here=' + _progressValue.toString());

    return AlertDialog(
      title: new Text('Downloading ' + _files[index].name + ' ...'),
      content: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context,StateSetter setState) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 30,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(value: _progressValue),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

and my download function looks like this

```
static Future<void> downloadGoogleDriveFile(String fName, String googleDriveId, String fileSize, Function updateProgress, Function dialogCallback) async {
    var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
    ga.Media file = await drive.files.get(googleDriveId, downloadOptions: ga.DownloadOptions.FullMedia);

    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final saveFile = File('${directory.path}/${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}$fName');
    List<int> dataStore = [];

    file.stream.listen((data) {
      dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, data);

      if (updateProgress != null)
        updateProgress((dataStore.length / double.parse(fileSize)) * 100);
    }, onDone: () {
      saveFile.writeAsBytes(dataStore);
      Toast.show('File saved at ${saveFile.path}');

      if (dialogCallback != null)
        dialogCallback();

      if (client != null)
        client.close();
    }, onError: (error) {
      Toast.showError(error.toString());

      if (dialogCallback != null)
        dialogCallback();

      if (client != null)
        client.close();
    });
  }
```

I think the reason why it does not refresh the alertdialog is because the setState called should be the one inside AlertDialog's StatefulBuilder, am i correct? But i have no idea how to do that. if i place downloadGoogleDriveFile() inside the statefulBuilder's block section it might get called again once setState is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using line of code

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context,setState){

         double _progressValue;
    downloadGoogleDriveFile(_files[index].name, _files[index].googleDriveId, _files[index].size,
      (double progress) {
        setState(() {
          _progressValue = progress;
          print('set state progress value='+_progressValue.toString());
        });
      },
      () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });

    print('progress here=' + _progressValue.toString());


        return  AlertDialog(
      title: new Text('Downloading ' + _files[index].name + ' ...'),
      content:  SizedBox(
            height: 30,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(value: _progressValue),
          ),
    );
      },
    );


  },
);
```

I Hope will help

Comment: I tried that approach and i get a looping error "This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build)."

Comment: i am using a library called progress dialog that shields this setState() issue within AlertDialog. but i still am interested to get this to work to better understand.